# Excel IF statement with SUM in it

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need help with this IF statement on Excel.

The logic behind it is:

IF the Column C content is equal to "Unloading in progress" OR "Ready for unload", THEN add the number on Column D. Display tat number.

or it can also be something like this:

SUM the number on Column D if and only if Column C is equal to "Unloading in progress" OR "Ready for unload". For this one I tried`=SUMIF(D:D,OR(C:C="Unloading in progress",C:C="Ready for unload"),D:D)`but it didn't work.

So when that formula works the table in the picture attached, should display 8,931.

[image: Excel Question]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
=SUMIF(C:C,"Ready for unload",D:D)+SUMIF(C:C,"Unloading in progress",D:D)
```

You could also do it using an *array formula* as follows, but as mentioned in the comments, your performance may be better using a standard non-array formula:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(D:D,C:C,{"Unloading in progress","Ready for unload"}))
```

Note that when entering an array formula, you have to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> when you do so.

Comment: Using Array formula on whole columns is a bad idea.

Comment: @chrisneilsen, in what regard? Performance? I added a non-array alternative too.

Comment: Yes, performance.   Most (but not all) regular formula are optimised to only process filled data, so suffer no performance loss on whole columns.  Array formula aren't optimised like that, so will calculate all 1,000,000+ rows

Comment: @chris in this case it is only iterating twice and is no slower than the first formula.

Answer (score 0):

Add the individual SUMIF's

```
=SUMIF(D:D,C:C,"Unloading in progress") + SUMIF(D:D,C:C,"Ready for unload")
```

Comment: You have the formula wrong. `SUMIF` and `SUMIFS` have different signatures. Your syntax for `SUMIF`-- which looks to have been adapted from my `SUMIFS` example-- is not valid.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I meant to use sumifs, fat fingered...

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
= SUMPRODUCT( $D$2:$D$16,
 ($C$2:$C$16 = "Unloading in progress") + ($C$2:$C$16 = "Ready for unload") )
```